# How to include PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser right

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, simple-html-dom

I call my PHP-function via AJAX, but I get the error-message only. The error start, when I use a function (file_get_html) from right included simple_html_dom.php. But I don't not why. Do you have an answer?

I reduced the function to the not working parts:

AJAX:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn-holeVorlagenKategorien", function () {


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/app.php",
        data: {
            action: "getHTML"
        },
        success: function(data){
            var response = $.parseJSON(data);
            var html = response.html;
            alert(html);            
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("There is an error.");
        }
    });

});
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
      if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) {
        $action = $_POST["action"];
        switch($action) {
      case "getHTML": getHTML(); break;
    }
  }
}

function getHTML(){

        $url="http://www.msn.com";

        require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/assets/php/simple_html_dom.php";
        $html = file_get_html($url); // pars

        # Antwort geben 
        print_r(json_encode(array(
            "status"=>$query,
            "html"=>$html
            )));
        }
```

The Structure of My Application looks like this:

```
    App                                (DIR - APP-ROOT)
        ---index.php                   (FILE)
       |--assets                       (DIR)
          |--css                       (DIR)     
              ---app.css               (FILE)
          |--img                       (DIR)
              ---pix-1.jpg             (FILE)
              ---pix-2.jpg             (FILE)
          |--js                        (DIR)
              ---app.js                (FILE)
          |--php                       (DIR)
              ---simple_html_dom.php   (FILE)
       |--php                          (DIR)
          ---ajax.php                  (FILE)
          ---some_file.php             (FILE)
```

Comment: How is your Application structured? Can you show us a graphical interpretation of the Directories in your Application. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` might not return what you expected - depending on the structure of the Directories in your App. At least show us where `simple_html_dom.php` lives relative to your AJAX Processing PHP File...

Comment: is your usage of `print_r` for debug? it should probably be `echo`, otherwise you'll be introducing unexpected characters

Comment: You may edit the Pseudo-Structure of your App appended to your original Post to reflect the actual Structure... You may not have to capture the entire Structure but only those related to the `simple_html_dom.php`, the `Root of your App` and `the AJAX Processing Script`. This may help everyone (*if you will*)

Comment: To debug this sort of Ajax stuff you might want to log trace writes to a file inside you server-side PHP. It is really the only way to get any visibility. I would suggest you write a little Trace($data) function that opens a file and appends the $data string. Then you can check that file to see where your script is getting to.